# What are the device-specific CMPedometer features supported in individual iPhone and Apple Watch models?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-watch

I am interested in knowing which Core Motion - Pedometer (`CMPedometer`) features are supported in which iPhone models.

Specifically I am interested in the `bool` values of the following properties:

```
isCadenceAvailable()
isStepCountingAvailable()
isPaceAvailable()
isDistanceAvailable()
isPedometerEventTrackingAvailable()
isFloorCountingAvailable()
```

I have access to an iPhone SE and a 5s.
On those models, I got the following response:

**5s**

```
isCadenceAvailable: false
isStepCountingAvailable: true
isPaceAvailable: false
isDistanceAvailable: true
isPedometerEventTrackingAvailable: false
isFloorCountingAvailable: false
```

**SE**

```
isCadenceAvailable: true
isStepCountingAvailable: true
isPaceAvailable: true
isDistanceAvailable: true
isPedometerEventTrackingAvailable: true
isFloorCountingAvailable: false
```

I would love it if other members can submit info for the other iPhone models: 6, 6s, 7, 8, X, XR, XS, XS Max. I believe XR, XS and XS Max would provide the same results, as should 8 and X.

---

Also, similar results for Apple Watch models is also welcome. Here's the data for

**S0**

```
isCadenceAvailable: true
isStepCountingAvailable: true
isPaceAvailable: true
isDistanceAvailable: true
isPedometerEventTrackingAvailable: true
isFloorCountingAvailable: false
```

---

Here's the code for printing this out:

**iOS**

```
import UIKit
import CoreMotion

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        print("isCadenceAvailable: \(CMPedometer.isCadenceAvailable())")
        print("isStepCountingAvailable: \(CMPedometer.isStepCountingAvailable())")
        print("isPaceAvailable: \(CMPedometer.isPaceAvailable())")
        print("isDistanceAvailable: \(CMPedometer.isDistanceAvailable())")
        print("isPedometerEventTrackingAvailable: \(CMPedometer.isPedometerEventTrackingAvailable())")
        print("isFloorCountingAvailable: \(CMPedometer.isFloorCountingAvailable())")
    }
}
```

**watchOS**

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import CoreMotion

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {
    @IBOutlet var boolLabel: WKInterfaceLabel!

    override func willActivate() {
        super.willActivate()
        let b1 = CMPedometer.isDistanceAvailable() ? "Y" : "N"
        let b2 = CMPedometer.isStepCountingAvailable() ? "Y" : "N"
        let b3 = CMPedometer.isCadenceAvailable() ? "Y" : "N"
        let b4 = CMPedometer.isPaceAvailable() ? "Y" : "N"
        let b5 = CMPedometer.isPedometerEventTrackingAvailable() ? "Y" : "N"
        let b6 = CMPedometer.isFloorCountingAvailable() ? "Y" : "N"
        let str = b1 + b2 + b3 + b4 + b5 + b6

        boolLabel.setText(str)
    }
}
```

This question is about the info for the other iPhone and watch models. Unfortunately, checking this via the Simulator generates false for all the boolean values. Feel free to copy-paste the above code and run on your device to provide the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I have been asking myself a similar question and thus prepared a repo with a simple project to help track the availability of features.

https://github.com/reggian/availability

I would gradually fill in the missing data and add other frameworks that have different availability across different hardware.

Please feel free to contribute.